# Get selected values from dxe:ComboBoxEdit

Tags: c#, xaml, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress ComboboxEdit object to get multiple selection from the user. My problem is that I am not sure what type of object will come back once a selection has been done.

I have read [this one](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q383783), and came up with the code below, but I am not sure what I am missing. (I also don't know exactly what a `DependencyProperty` is, but would like to avoid too many objects)

```
<Window x:Class = "Demo.MainWindow"
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:Demo"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             xmlns:dxl="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
   mc:Ignorable = "d"
   Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "525">

    <StackPanel>

        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
                          IsTextEditable="False"
                          EditValue="{Binding Path=MySelectedList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Name="abc">
            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
                <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings/>
            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>

        <Button Click="showSelected" Content="Show selected items" />

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Text;

namespace Demo
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> _myList;
        private System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> _mySelectedList; // This has probably the wrong type.

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


        public IList<string> MyList
        {
            get
            {
                return _myList;
            }

            set
            {
                _myList = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
            }
        }

        public IList<string> MySelectedList
        {
            get
            {
                return _mySelectedList;
            }

            set
            {
                _mySelectedList = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("MySelectedList");
            }
        }

        private void showSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach(string s in this.MySelectedList)
            {
                sb.Append(s);
            }
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
            // This MessageBox show show whatever is checked.
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            MySelectedList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

            MyList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
            MyList.Add("a");
            MyList.Add("b");
            MyList.Add("c");
            MyList.Add("d");

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it and click the combobox, then a red `X` appears and says that `The type System.Collection.Generic.List´1[System.Object] could not be converted`. And the MessageBox is always empty.

Comment: Try implementing System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged on the MainWindow

Comment: @Carson Done, also raised the event in the setters, no visible effect. Should I somehow register handlers or is the WPF registering the view elements for me?

Comment: You should not need to register any handlers. Please update your code and I will try to update my answer.

Comment: @Carson  Just updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditValue` property contains a list of objects, so your code in VM should look like this:

```
private List<object> _mySelectedList;

public List<object> MySelectedList
{
    get
    {
        return _mySelectedList;
    }

    set
    {
        _mySelectedList = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("MySelectedList");
    }
}
```

Or you can write `EditValue` converter, example you will find [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q513117).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) implemented on your `MainWindow`, but that may not be the only issue. I would read up on [Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx) before you really try to tinker with WPF. If you do not understand those concepts everything will be difficult and confusing.

**EDIT**

They are using a `DependencyProperty` (As you mentioned) it seems. But anyway, this is how you would implement one

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(IList), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
    if (mainWindow != null)
        mainWindow.OnSelectedItemsChanged((IList)e.OldValue, (IList)e.NewValue);
}

protected virtual void OnSelectedItemsChanged(IList oldValue, IList newValue)
{
    // Add your property changed side-effects. Descendants can override as well.
}

public IList SelectedItems
{
    // IMPORTANT: To maintain parity between setting a property in XAML and procedural code, do not touch the getter and setter inside this dependency property!
    get
    {
        return (IList)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Notice it needs to be of type `IList` and you will need to cast to type `string`

Also, remove the `Mode=TwoWay` as it is not needed in your binding.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" EditValue="{Binding SelectedItems}" >
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
        <dxe:CheckedComboBoxStyleSettings/>
    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.StyleSettings>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

You also do not need `INotifyPropertyChanged` that was my mistake. I thought you were doing traditional binding.

Comment: Why is the DependencyProperty odd? Do you have a better idea?

Comment: No, I guess it isn't "Odd" per se, but I feel like finding a more traditional means of managing the binding would be more intuitive. For instance, if they had a "SelectedItems" property you could bind to that returned an `IEnumerable` or something. It isn't usual to have to create a new `DependencyProperty` to bind to a property IMO, and it certainly is not helpful if you want to maintain rigid MVVM. But, you can always bind to your `DependencyProperty` too, so there is a way around it, I suppose. I am probably just being overly opinionated.

Comment: My gripe is more thinking out loud about the way DevExpress sometimes handles bindings, but it is just my opinion, it doesn't mean much.